# Pandas groupby object in legend on plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a pandas `groupby` object using the code `fil.groupby('imei').plot(x=['time'],y = ['battery'],ax=ax, title = str(i))`

The problem is the plot legend lists `['battery']`as the legend value. Given it's drawing a line for each item in the `groupby` object, it makes more sense to plot those values in the legend instead. However I'm not sure how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Data

```
                 time             imei  battery_raw
0 2016-09-30 07:01:23  862117020146766        42208
1 2016-09-30 07:06:23  862117024146766        42213
2 2016-09-30 07:11:23  862117056146766        42151
3 2016-09-30 07:16:23  862117995146745        42263
4 2016-09-30 07:21:23  862117020146732        42293
```

Full code

```
for i in entity:
    fil = df[(df['entity_id']==i)]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,6))
    fil.groupby('imei').plot(x=['time'],y = ['battery'],ax=ax, title = str(i))  
    plt.legend(fil.imei)
    plt.show()
```

Current plot

[image]

Comment: Could you post an example dataframe that is used as input for the groupby method?

Comment: what is `fil.imei`?  what happens if you just do `ax.legend()`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Slightly tidied data:

```
    date         time             imei      battery_raw
0 2016-09-30 07:01:23  862117020146766       42208
1 2016-09-30 07:06:23  862117020146766        42213
2 2016-09-30 07:11:23  862117020146766        42151
3 2016-09-30 07:16:23 862117995146745       42263
4 2016-09-30 07:21:23  862117995146745       42293
```

Complete example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fil = pd.read_csv('imei.csv', sep=r'\s*', engine='python')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,6))

for name, group in fil.groupby('imei'):
    group.plot(x=pd.to_datetime(group['time']), y='battery_raw', ax=ax, label=name)

plt.show()
```

The x-values have to be converted to datetime for plotting to come out right, as usual. You could do that in the dataframe, too.

Result, labeled by imei:

[image]
(NOTE: edited to get rid of an oddity I tripped over the first time. If you pass a list as the `y` argument to `group.plot`, the list IDs will be used as the line labels, presumably as a handy default for when you're plotting several dependent variables at once.

```
#for name, group in fil.groupby('imei'):
#    group.plot(x=['time'], y=['battery_raw'], ax=ax, label=name)
```

)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby.SeriesGroupBy.plot` instead of `groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.plot` to put the group name as legend instead of the column name.

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fp = StringIO("""
time,imei,battery
2016-09-30 07:01:23,862117024146766,42208
2016-09-30 07:06:23,862117024146766,42213
2016-09-30 07:11:23,862117024146766,42151
2016-09-30 07:16:23,862117995146745,42263
2016-09-30 07:21:23,862117995146745,42293
""")

df = pd.read_csv(fp)
df = df.set_index("time")

f, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(16, 6))

# Original
df.groupby('imei').plot(
    y='battery', ax=axes[0], title="groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.plot"
)

# Solution
df.groupby('imei')['battery'].plot(
    ax=axes[1], title="groupby.SeriesGroupBy.plot", legend=True
)
```

[image]