# Seaborn lineplot connecting points in incorrect order for x vs y plot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

For a 3-panel plot using seaborn lineplot (also tried with relplot with the same result) in the center and right panels some points are missing or plotted incorrectly. I set sort to False so it should, as I understand, plot points in the index order. From the sample data (linked below), the rightmost plot for method 3 should consist of the points:

bin (y) diff (x)
1500 -5
1700 -5
1900 -12
2100 -16.5
2300 -19.5
2500 -9
2700 -5
2900 -3

connected in that order. But the line does not show the first two points correctly. The line for method 0 is even worse, where the bin (y) value of the first point should be 1500. As sorted, the y-values should increase along each line from 1500 to 2900, and those two examples don't follow that. The method 0 line in the center panel also shows the y-value dropping toward the upper end.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("sample_data.csv")
print df[0:5]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,4), ncols=3, nrows=1, sharey=True)
xcols = ['hist','fut','diff']
n=-1
for ax in axes.flatten():
    n += 1
    if n > 0:
        sns.lineplot(data=df,x=xcols[n],y='bin',hue='method',sort=False,ax=ax,legend=False,ci=None)
    else:
        sns.lineplot(data=df,x=xcols[n],y='bin',hue='method',sort=False,ax=ax,legend='brief',ci=None)
plt.show()
```

[image: sample plot]

sample data area [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qhj6e69zwz2bh6h/sample_data.csv?dl=0).

Any help in figuring out what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated.

Update: I found a workaround by avoiding Seaborn (from [this helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902522/pandas-groupby-object-in-legend-on-plot)):

```
for n,i in enumerate(axes):
    for name, group in df.groupby('method'):
        group.plot(x=xcols[n],y='bin',ax=axes[n],label=name,legend=False)
handles, labels = axes[n].get_legend_handles_labels()
fig.legend(handles, labels, loc=7)
```

But that doesn't answer the question about seaborn.

Comment: I don't think its obvious in how far the resulting plot is incorrect.

Comment: Please add the CSV data in order to make this a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).